# Fastest way to map Dictionary to array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, dictionary

What is the fastest way to convert a Dictionary with integer index to an array such that the array index is the Dictionary index? You can assume the Dictionary contains all elements from 0 to the maximum key.

Example:

```
dictionary[2] = z
dictionary[0] = x
dictionary[1] = y
```

After conversion I need:

```
array[0] = x
array[1] = y
array[2] = z
```

Comment: Using LINQ you could do sth like  myDict.Select(x => x.Value).ToArray();

Comment: @apomene That does not guarantee that the key values will be in order.  I believe the OP wants the value in `dictionary[n]` to equal the value in `array[n]` for all n from 0 to the max key value.

Comment: dictionaries are stored as a binary tree so index really doesn't make a lot of sense.   Why would anybody use index with a dictionary unless you are printing a table.

Answer (score 2):

If the key/value in the dictionary contains the index in the array you want to put the value to you can just iterate over the dictionary and insert the value to specific index.

```
Dictionary<int, string> keyValuePairs = new Dictionary<int, string>();
string[] arr = new string[keyValuePairs.Count];

foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> item in keyValuePairs)
    arr[item.Key] = item.Value;
```

Should you have indexes not incrementing uniformly as @TanvirArjel suggested - you should first find the maximum index which would mean replacing the second line to the following:

```
string[] arr = new string[keyValuePairs.Keys.Max() + 1];
```

Speed wise, it's always better to use non-lazy programming and define your types.. you'll get a smaller performance increase over using vars *when iterating* (Supporting argument below).

There's a great Microsoft Article [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/48007.c-different-ways-of-iterating-over-a-dictionary-and-their-performance.aspx) comparing the ways of iteration and their speed on Dictionaries.

Comment: It will throw `index out of range` if Dictionary Key is not increase uniformly.

Comment: @TanvirArjel It would, but that's not part of the question OP had, the question stated "dictionary contains all elements from 0 to the maximum key" suggesting they are uniformly present. It's a good thing to keep in mind for the OP though. Feel free to edit the answer.

Comment: Actually you want `new string[keyValuPars.Keys.Max() +1]` because indexes start at 0 so the size is one greater than the max index.

Comment: @juharr Sorry, you're correct. I looked at the first example when I posted my first comment.

Comment: But will replacing string[] with var can result in any performance improvement?

var can make some difference on some scenarios where a class  implements a Interface for eg :
`IA a = new A();` 
var a = new A();
this case as you said some difference is there ..

Comment: @ShyamKumar see the supporting link. I was speaking about the iterator not the array declaration. I've also put that in now to avoid further confusion.

Comment: @Adriani6 ya, you are correct. thank u for sharing the information

Comment: @Adriani6 and do you know why this improvement happens. thanks